# pick 2 tables value for a specific column

Tags: php, mysql

```
table1: Proid   email        password   verify
        12345   john@xx.com  xxxxxxx     xxxx
        45678   lee@xx.com   xxxxxxx     xxxx
        // some more tables here

table2: Proid   fname    lname   gender  dofbirth 
        13456    rey      aj      male    xxxxx
        12345    john     paul    male    xxxxx
        47812    murray   dj      male    xxxxx
        45678    lee      mah     female  xxxxx
```

**Note** this tables dont have duplicates of `Proid`

now here `Proid` is common for both the tables what i wanted is, to fetch an array simple as this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT table1.verify,table1.Email,table2.* FROM table1,table2 WHERE table2.Pro_ID='$pro_id' LIMIT 1"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
// and I expect $row variable now has this values
 $row['email'],$row['verify'],$row['fname'],row['lname'],row['table2*']
```

but no matter what its taking the first entry. How coud I fix this. is this the way to do it? Could anyone post or suggest me a good way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens with your query:

```
SELECT table1.verify, table1.Email, table2.*
//means: In each row include columns 'verify' and 'email'
//       from table1 and all columns from table2.

FROM table1, table2 
//means: Combine EACH row of table1 with EACH row of table2.

WHERE table2.Pro_ID='$pro_id'
//means: Fetch only rows where the 'pro_id' column
//       of table2 has the specified value.

LIMIT 1
//means: Fetch only the first row.
```

So, what actually happens is that you combine **each** row of table1 with the row of table2 that has `Pro_ID='$pro_id'` (resulting in 4 rows for your example tables above) and then return the 1st row (which **always** contains the values of the 1st row of table1).

---

The problem is that there is no contsraint that forces the matching of rows from table1 and table2 **only** when their `pro_id` values are the same.

You can fix this in several ways.

1.) Add an additional condition in your `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE table1.Pro_ID = table2.Pro_ID
  AND table2.Pro_ID = '$pro_id'
...
```

2.) Joining the tables on column 'Pro_ID':

```
...
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
  ON table1.Pro_ID = table2.Pro_ID
...
```

(More info on **[SQL joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)**.)

Answer (score 1):

change this:

```
SELECT table1.verify,table1.Email,table2.* FROM table1,table2 
            WHERE table2.Pro_ID='$pro_id' LIMIT 1
```

to:

```
SELECT table1.verify,table1.Email,table2.* FROM table1 
           left join table2 on table1.Proid=table2.Proid 
           where table2.Proid in not null LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it joins the two tables where Proid`s match and returns results that have a match. Entries from table1 that have no match in table2 do not get returned.